# Suspend autoscaling processes through Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, infrastructure-as-code, yaml

I have the following autoscaling as a Cloudformation template :

```
  MyAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      DesiredCapacity: 1
      MinSize: 1
      MaxSize: 1
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref MyLaunchConfiguration
      AvailabilityZones: !GetAZs
```

I am struggling with defining [suspended processes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html) inside Cloudformation template.

Trying an intuitive approach ( adding it as property) and it does not work at all :

```
  MyAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      DesiredCapacity: 1
      MinSize: 1
      MaxSize: 1
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref MyLaunchConfiguration
      AvailabilityZones: !GetAZs
      SuspendedProcesses:
        - AZRebalance
        - Terminate
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Hello @Tensibai, I got it. Thank you for your interesting.

Comment: I followed the same, but once the autoscaling group is created without having any SuspenProcess properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it from [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) of UpdatePolicy . Indeed, we can suspend processes by using the `UpdatePolicy` attribute for the `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` resource :

- So instead of `SuspendedProcesses`, the right term is `SuspendProcesses`.
- Also instead of putting `SuspendProcesses` under `Properties`, it should be under `UpdatePolicy > AutoScalingRollingUpdate` .

_

```
  MyAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      DesiredCapacity: 1
      MinSize: 1
      MaxSize: 1
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref MyLaunchConfiguration
      AvailabilityZones: !GetAZs
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        SuspendProcesses:
        - AZRebalance
        - Terminate
```

Comment: This suspends the processes during updates to the ASG via the CF stack, not in general (CF resumes the processes when it is done updating the ASG).